# Raw input is reading at the beginning of the program regardless of how the code is ordered

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having a simple issue in Python where I'm reading user input, but my program is always reading input immediately at the start of the program.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python   
def test():
    input = raw_input("enter in something:")
    print input

def main():
    print('Hello World!')
    test()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see, the program is supposed to print 'Hello World' first, print 'enter in something:', and then ask for user input. What's it's doing instead is:
Read input => 'Hello World' => 'enter in something'
What's causing this issue?

Comment: Possibly IO buffering ... You could try `sys.stdout.flush()` or starting the program via `python -u`

Comment: For me (python 2.7.9 and 2.7.10) this code works correct both on win and linux platform.

Comment: sys.stdout.flush() didn't work, but adding -u did.

Comment: yes, its working fine on Linux!

Comment: Most likely, you are running a version of the program where the test() is called before the print statement. Be sure to double check where the program is stored, and finally check that the code is exactly the one you have posted here.